# Problem with data labels apexcharts using angular 8+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, apexcharts

I have a problem to populate data in the last and first data labels.
When the graph has few bars, the data labels do not appear. Follow the photos below to view!

[Click to see the image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysp8E.png)

[Click to see the image without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiNYv.png)

Comment: It's a bug in ApexCharts which I have just fixed here - https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/commit/29f0df A new version will be released soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am waiting for the update!